# Integration Tests fail to connect, Manual Browser Test succeeds with Java RESTful Web Service with SpringBoot/Jsoup Integration Test

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, integration-testing

I'm trying to run the sample code in this book: [Building RESTful Web Services with Spring 5 - Second Edition](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/building-restful-web-services-spring-5-second-edition). You can download the sample code for free. In chapter 7, they have some sample code that includes some integration tests and unit tests all in same directory "chapter7\ticketmanagement/src/test/java/com/packtpub/restapp/ticketmanagement/". The unit tests work fine.  The integration tests fail with "testUsersJsoup(com.packtpub.restapp.ticketmanagement.JsoupUserTest)  Time elapsed: 1.011 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect"

I experimented with changing the port from 8080 to 9090 in "ticket-management\src\main\resources\application.properties" (I also changed the hardcoded values in the integration test) and this did not help.

So "mvn test" produces the above error.
So does running them in spring tool suite.
I edited the original pom.xml and added the "maven-compiler-plugin" to specify java version 1.8. I'm running windows 10.

So the failing code is in "chapter 7\ticket-management\src\test\java\com\packtpub\restapp\ticketmanagement\JsoupUserTest.java".

Here is the failing code:

```
public void testUsersJsoup() throws IOException {

    String doc = Jsoup.connect("http://localhost:9090/user").ignoreContentType(true).get().body().text();

    _log.info("{test} doc : " + doc);

    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement userElement = parser.parse(doc);
    JsonArray userArray = userElement.getAsJsonArray();

    _log.info("{test} size : " + userArray.size());

    assertEquals(4, userArray.size());
}
```

HOWEVER, when I type

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

it starts successfully and I point my chrome browser to http://localhost:9090/user (or http://localhost:8080/user if I am using the original code) I see

```
[{"userid":100,"username":"David"},{"userid":101,"username":"Peter"},{"userid":102,"username":"John"}]
```

No connection error! The results look correct.

1. We know this is not a firewall problem because it is just with localhost and it works with chrome.
2. There is no proxy involved.
3. I think the ports are correct: I presently have 9090 in the application.properities file, and in the  source code and in the browser.
4. "mvn clean" and then "mvn test" again did not help.

Comment: OK, silly me. I assumed that since I saw the spring ASCII art banner scroll by that the "mvn test" command was also starting up the web server. It is not. When I manually start the web server in another process with "mvn spring-boot:run" all the tests pass. But the new feature of spring is that it can run tomcat or jetty. So the new question is, how do I enhance the pom.xml to automatically start the default web server when running tests? Perhaps the problem is that the failing test is really an integration test and not a unit test?

Answer (score 0):

There are annotations to start the web app as exemplified here:
[Spring Live Lessons Tutorial](https://github.com/livelessons-spring/building-microservices) and they work. See %JAVA_BUILDINGMICROSERVICES%\livelessons-security\livelessons-security-basic\src\test\java\basic\BasicSecurityApplicationTests.java.

These annotations have been deprecated, and replaced by newer ones. The problem is that the author of this tutorial is not using theses new annotations correctly: he needs to also use @WebAppConfiguration and this requires some configuration arguments from the @SpringBootTest (which  he is missing). Therefor it necessary to manually start the web server with "mvn spring-boot:run" in a separate process and then run the tests.

When I tried to use @WebAppConfiguation, I got other errors. I will document these errors in another post (some day).